# What is the plastic tubing that DIP's come in

Tags: identification, dip

I'm looking to protect some old vintage MOS chips that I own and I don't want this to sound like a stupid question, but I cannot find the name of the plastic tubing that DIP chips can be purchased in.

I've looked up things like "dip chip tube" or "chip plastic cover" but to no avail.

I have actually purchased some old 8-bit CPU's (all DIP's) that came in this kind of tubing that I'm looking for the others and it conforms to its shape.

[image: Chips in tube]

Does anybody know what these are called and if they are available to buy empty?

Comment: IC Storage Tubes?
https://www.jameco.com/z/RIC-20-0-30-Wide-Plastic-IC-Storage-Tubes_29516.html

Comment: @Bart Oh gosh. Yes. Thankyou!

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/310290/what-is-this-plastic-chip-packing-material-called possible duplicate in the answers

Comment: Don't forget that for MOS circuits you must get **anti-static** tubes and bags for storage.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Thankyou for the warning. I was about to buy some now so I will make sure to get them