# Are IC rail tubes sufficient protection for ESD-safe storage?

Tags: esd, packages, storage

I've ended up with a collection of spare IC chips and am wondering what lengths I need to take to store them properly with respect to ESD.

Depending on their size they tend to come from the supplier in either a [plastic tube](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/382700/what-is-the-plastic-tubing-that-dips-come-in) or a cut length of tape which itself is packed in a silvered anti-static bag.

These plastic tubes usually have ESD-related markings on them but are not measurably conductive when probed with a multimeter either. Are the tapes/tubes **themselves** sufficient to protect contained components, or merely *compatible* somehow with the rest of an ESD-safe system (i.e. only just one "part of a complete breakfast" as it were)?

If I collect my "extra" chips into these leftover tubes at a grounded workstation, can I then treat the outside without regard to ESD precautions? Or do they need to go back into a silvered bag, the way they were shipped originally, before leaving an ESD safe environment?

Asking primarily as a hobbyist but would also be interested in the "proper" answer for production contexts.

Comment: You've got be careful with ESD markings.  The typical ones I've seen indicate that the parts themselves are ESD sensitive.  Here's a reference: https://scs-static-control-solutions.blog/2018/06/28/esd-symbols-you-need-to-know/

Comment: @SteveSh Literally every single vendor in China gets this wrong. The ESD-safe mats, packages and grounding kits themselves are all incorrectly marked using the "vulnerable to ESD" symbol. It's hilarious.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot measure whether something is able to leak away ESD charge with a multimeter. The resistances required for something to be static dissipative are just too high for a normal meter. You need large electrodes and high test voltages.

Also "ESD-safe" has varying degrees:

**Dissipative:** slowly leaks away charge which eliminates charge build-up and suppresses discharges through the material itself

**Conductive:** quickly leaks away charge which eliminates charge build-up but does not suppress ESD discharges through the material

**Low-charge generation:** Reduces charge build-up. Does NOT leak away charge. Does NOT suppress ESD discharges.

**Shielding/Metallic Foil Bags:** Technically falls under conductive but is structured such that when the package is sealed actually does protect the inner contents from ESD discharges.

If it's cheap packaging that is not metallic and not black it is probably low-charge generation at best. I assume all cheap packaging that is translucent, transparent, blue, and/or pink but non-metallic as low-charge generation.